# Implementing Custom Signals or Events in PySide6 App for Fancy Zones Integration

Tags: pyqt, pyside6, power-toys

I'm working on a PySide6 application where I want to integrate with Fancy Zones. I'm attempting to implement custom signals or events associated with a custom bar to trigger specific layouts or behaviors in Fancy Zones based on interactions with this bar.

I've explored the possibility of sending synthetic QMoveEvents using PySide6's QWindow.sendEvent method when the custom bar is dragged. This approach is aimed at tricking Fancy Zones into thinking the window is being repositioned and, in turn, triggering its layout logic.
However, I'm facing challenges, particularly when the application window lacks a title bar or has a custom title bar. In these cases, dragging doesn't activate Fancy Zones.

I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to effectively create custom signals or events for interactions with the custom bar and successfully integrate with Fancy Zones.